# Pinterest Followers display

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, api, pinterest

How would I go about showing my Pinterest followers in Wordpress? I tried [this](http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_follow_me_button) but it only displays the button letting users to follow my account, nothing about my followers.

Presumably, I can do this using the Pinterest API, but I'm unsure where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try creating your widget using this link : http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button It has a "Pin Count" option. Is your "data-pin-config" set?

Comment: it doesn't work. it only works for pins, not account itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Pinterest API. Install curl and use that in a PHP script. Example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://pinterestapi.co.uk/"""yourname"""/likes');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It's supposed to return something like this note that """yourname""" is your Pinterest account name:

```
{
"body": [
{
"href": "http://pinterest.com/pin/150026231307331200/",
"src": "http://media-cache-ec3.pinterest.com/upload/228979962274567868_qVshovBS_b.jpg",
"desc": "#london",
"user": "Louise Earl",
"via": "Kris Mitchell",
"board": "Ideal"
},
{
"href": "http://pinterest.com/pin/287104544965407998/",
"src": "http://media-cache-ec8.pinterest.com/upload/287104544965407998_z3kbynbX_b.jpg",
"desc": "hipsters vs old people",
"user": "Lucy Foulkes",
"via": false,
"board": "cool"
}
],
"meta": {
"count": 2
}
}
```

Since this returns a json string you´ll need to decode it.

```
$count = json_decode($json, true);
$count = $count['meta']['count'];
```

I don't know if curl is available when hosting your site on Wordpress but might be worth a try. In your case the "count" in that string is probably what you want.

Comment: np glad I could help you out :D. Thank you for that bounty , too.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.
To get the number of account followers:

```
<?php
$metas = get_meta_tags('http://pinterest.com/pinterest/');
print_r($metas['pinterestapp:followers']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it with this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-badge/

I added it as a widget. I made the number of pins = 0 and no title.

See screenshot below:

[image]

You can edit the styles to your liking as well as change the "Followed by..." text in the plugin files!

Comment: I think your solution more or less works for me. But I am planning to host my site on `wordpress.com` once I am done with theming and stuff. And don't think sites hosted on `wordpress.com` are able to use plugins. I will give it a shot nevertheless. Withholding the bounty amount in case someone comes up with a better solution. :)

Comment: How are you using wordpress.com on localhost? I haven't really used wordpress.com...

Comment: I downloaded wordpress to run on my localhost, just for theming purpose. Once I am done, I am pushing the theme to wordpress.com

Comment: Because of the way WordPress.com’s technical infrastructure is designed, we are not able to support uploading of custom WordPress themes on our service. http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/adding-new-themes/

Comment: @parzival WP.com does not accept custom themes nor plugins, you'll get only what's offered by the service.

Comment: Thank you all. Yeah it seems like a futile attempt.